# Why doesn't my second cron task get run?

Tags: 14.04, cron

I have these two task to be run. The first one gets run every 1 minutes and I want the second one to be run at hour:minute every day every month.

```
*/1 * * * * python /root/vine/hei.py

22 20 * * * python /root/vine/hello.py (to run everyday at 20:22)
```

I waited from 20:20 my local time and see if these two will be run. The second one never gets run when the first one does. Why is it that?

Comment: did you check the path of your 2nd script and that it is runnable ? I don't see any crontab syntax failure.

Comment: Does the second python program reference files without a full path?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is pretty obvious but just to exclude this type of error I have to ask it.
Does the second crontab really look like:
`22 20 * * * python /root/vine/hello.py (to run everyday at 20:22)`.
If so then remove the part in braces because that's wrong or put a # in front of that part which makes it a comment.